# Sort in MongooseJS 3.3.1 in ascending and descending order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have REST based API in NodeJS and MongooseJS ODM. To **GET** the list of *departments* URL is ***http://localhost:25718/Department?SortBy=Name&SortType=asc***(desc-for descending). And sorting code is

```
 var Query = Department.find();
 if(req.query.SortBy) {
        Query.sort(req.query.SortBy, 1);
        if(req.query.SortType) {
            if(req.query.SortType.toLowerCase() == 'desc') {
                Query.sort(req.query.SortBy, -1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This dose not works with MongooseJS 3.3.1 . **Query.sort(req.query.SortBy)** gives sorted in ascending order.But not getting descending in any way.
Please give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to recreate the problem you were experiencing.  I would say to post the information about the collection you are querying along with the indexes you have on it.

I did rewrite your code to be easier to read:

```
var Query = Department.find(),
    sortBy = req.query.SortBy,
    sortType = (req.query.SortType || 'asc').toLowerCase();

if (sortBy && sortType === 'asc') {
    Query.sort(sortBy, 1);  
} else if (sortBy && sortType === 'desc') {
    Query.sort(sortBy, -1);
}
```

---

**Update (2012-10-30)**

I just realized that I had the incorrect syntax for the sort function.  Please see corrected code.

```
var Query = Department.find(),
    sortBy = req.query.SortBy,
    sortType = (req.query.SortType || 'asc').toLowerCase();

if (sortBy && sortType === 'asc') {
    Query.sort(sortBy); // firstname
} else if (sortBy && sortType === 'desc') {
    Query.sort('-'+sortBy); // -firstname
}
```

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort for sort argument syntax.

Comment: The re-written code gives me the same error _**500 TypeError: Invalid sort() argument. Must be a string or object.**_ I am using Mongoose 3.3.1 ODM,present syntax is wrong,I tried different syntax even those from documentation, but not getting sorted.Since default is **ascending** , **Query.sort(sortBy);** is returning sorted in ascending.How to do descending?

Comment: I updated the code to use the correct sort function syntax. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains it here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: With my code I am getting error:_500 TypeError:Invalid sort() argument. Must be a string or object_.I tried code in documentation.My code `field = req.query.SortBy;
type = (req.query.SortType||'asc').toLowerCase();
if (field&&type==='asc') {
 Query.sort({field:'asc', type:1});
   }else if(field&&type==='desc'){
     Query.sort({field:'desc', type:-1});
      }` **also**  `if (field&&type==='asc') {
       Query.sort('field type');
       }else if(field&&type==='desc'){
        Query.sort('field -type');
     }` but its not returning in sorted order.

Comment: Instead of _req.query.SortBy_ or _field_  `Query.sort({ Name: 1 });` and `Query.sort({ Name: -1 });` gives sorted in ascending and descending. Here **Name** is the name of the field.There are 'n' number of fields for a model (like Name,Description,Address...) so field name cannot be given static,it changes in run time.How to give field name in run time? As default sort is ascending, `Query.sort(req.query.SortBy);` gives sorted in ascending,problem is with sort in descending. Please suggest a solution.